# Segmentation fault: 11 - Cross-reference to module

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to resolve an Segmentation Fault with Cross-references to modules. Don't know how to make this work. Part of error below:

```
1.  While reading from /Users/damiandudycz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hypno-azmcjycezcoqnfauqcbgimvipjyj/Build/Intermediates/Hypno.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hypno.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/WorldObjectBasedAugmentedRealityObject~partial.swiftmodule
2.  While deserializing 'WorldObjectBasedAugmentedRealityObject' (ClassDecl #12) 
3.  While deserializing decl #31 (XREF)
4.  Cross-reference to module 'AugmentedReality'
... AugmentedRealityView
... in an extension in module 'AugmentedReality'
... Object
5.  While loading members for 'AugmentedRealityView' at <invalid loc>
6.  While deserializing 'init' (ConstructorDecl #5) 
7.  While deserializing decl #33 (XREF)
8.  Cross-reference to module 'UIKit'
... UIView
... init
... with type (UIView.Type) -> (CGRect) -> UIView
```

Problem occurs when I'm subclassing a class that is a subclass of something from other module. And this class in other module inherits from UIView.
I have prepared an "empty" project version - I deleted most of the files and definitions, only empty classes are left and modules. Could someone help me with this? Problem shows in class GoogleARObject - when this class is deleted or commented it compiles.

Project with empty classes:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40968624/Hypno.zip

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:**

After having a deeper look in the issue it turns out that my answer is wrong.

Your code should compile fine, as you do not subclass `AugmentedRealityView` but a nested class.

The actual issue looks like a compiler bug to me.

You can workaround the issue by changing the `Swift Compiler` - `Optimization Level` to `Fast, Whole Module Optimization` instead of `None`:

[image]

---

**Original Answer:**

You are trying to inherit from a class (`AugmentedRealityView`) from outside the module the class is defined in, but it is marked `public` and `final`:

```
public final class AugmentedRealityView: UIView {
}

open class WorldObjectBasedAugmentedRealityObject: AugmentedRealityView {
}
```

`final` forbids to inherit from this class in general.

`public` allows to subclass from within the module the class is defined in (in Swift3).

To make a class subclass-able from outside the module it is defined in, use `open` (new in Swift3):

```
open class AugmentedRealityView: UIView {
}

open class WorldObjectBasedAugmentedRealityObject: AugmentedRealityView {
}
```

To learn more, read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3)

> You can mark an entire class as final by writing the final modifier before the class keyword in its class definition (final class). Any attempt to subclass a final class is reported as a compile-time error.

...

> Open access applies only to classes and class members, and it differs from public access as follows:
>
> Classes with public access, or any more restrictive access level, can be subclassed only within the module where they’re defined.
>
> Class members with public access, or any more restrictive access level, can be overridden by subclasses only within the module where they’re defined.
>
> Open classes can be subclassed within the module where they’re defined, and within any module that imports the module where they’re defined.
>
> Open class members can be overridden by subclasses within the module where they’re defined, and within any module that imports the module where they’re defined.

Comment: I didn't know about open. Thanks for that. (Voted)

Comment: And that worked, thank you :). Is this always a bad design to include nested classes inside extension? If they are visible only inside module is this ok?

Comment: Actually I have more places with such open classes inside extensions in module, and I inherit from them in different module. But only this one causes this problem. Why is that? for example I have public final class WebService: OperationQueue and extension for it extension WebService { open class RequestOperation: Operation {} }
Same situation, but works fine and I can inherit it in different modules.

Comment: And I actually am successfully inheriting A: AugmentedRealityView.AugmentedRealityViewObject, it's next level of inheriting causing problem. Could you give some more explanation to this? I'm curious how exactly this works and how what are correct ways of resolving this. I can even inherit A in the same file as A (which inherits from AugmentedRealityView.AugmentedRealityViewObject), but can't in other file. This is kinda weird.

Comment: I have prepared simple test project with such inheritance: 2 modules, in framework module class A, it's extension containing open class AA, and in main target class AA1: AA and AA2: AA1. Everything works without any problem. Whats the differece? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40968624/TestNestedTypesInheritance.zip

Comment: You are right, that is weird. Unfortunately I am busy and it will take time to have a deeper look. In general, I do not see a reason to make this a nested class. If you want to make it visible in the file its defined in only, use `fileprivate`.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

This error happens when you are referencing 2 different version of a same Framework at the same time. This can be the case when your code is using a different Swift version than one used by the library.

Try to use the same version of Swift than the one used by Google AR.

[image]

Comment: Old question, but just to say, it was not Google AR, it was an AR engine I was developing by myself. Worked very cool, but Apple ARKit shoved :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just encountered the same error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11 - Cross-reference to module
```

The solution in my case was to disable `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` (of course if it's possible for your project).

Answer (score 0):

[Here - chaosvoid's anser](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123426) was the solution I found and worked for me。

> problem solved,
>
> The import path is incomplete in the Objective-C Bridging Header file.
>
> Error import: import "A.h"
>
> Import correctly: import "A/A.h"