# Strange issue on converting function to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

I had a function in *Swift 2*:

```
public override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
```

and Xcode offered to convert it to *Swift 3*. I pressed the red dot to convert it, and it convert it into:

```
open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
```

but, now it gives me the next error:

```
Invalid redeclaration of 'draw'
```

How can I properly convert it to Swift 3?

Comment: Is that a global function, or a method on a type?  Also, have you already checked what the compiler says and seen if there is another function in the same scope that also has the type signature `draw(_:)`?

Comment: @DanielHall it method inside of the class. No there is not another draw(_:)
Compiler shows only the function i have posted here.

Comment: @Mighty Codder, could you please check if my solution provided works, and I think you are trying to override a method in a class that inherits from `UIView`, don't you?

Comment: @Mighty Codder, Maybe you can put the code of entire class here for further reference?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf it was inheriting from NSUIView I have even changed it to UIView. Your solution unfortunately did not work. XCode force me to add open in front of func and then and then says invalid declaration of draw

Comment: @MightyCodder, I think you should change that since Swift now is trying to migrate all his `NS..` classes, then try my solution, and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code (yours):

```
class MyView: UIView {
    open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        //
    }
}
```

Compiles fine here.

I suspect that you already have an implementation of `draw()` within your class.

Otherwize, clean and delete derived data.

Comment: @shalloThought, what is the purpose of using `open`?

Comment: `open` is not required in this case. I just wanted to state that the originally posted code works. Find more information about the `open` access level in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40633441/1457385

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your class is `UIView`, I think your method signature should only be:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
```

and it will work on Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode properly converted function

```
open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
```

I think that you had function with that name before and when Xcode converted drawRect you now have two functions with same name. I now tried it by myself and declaring draw function like above gives no errors. However when declaring such function 2 times gives exactly same error.